# how set a word limit in paragraph's sentences in python?

Tags: python, list, split, slice

Need to set a limit when append in a list.

```
sent = 'Python is dynamically-typed and garbage-collected. It supports multiple programming paradigms, including structured (particularly procedural), object-oriented and functional programming.'
```

I need to set only 5 words in one sentence and append to a list

output should -

```
sent_list = ['Python is dynamically-typed and garbage-collected.', 'It supports multiple programming paradigms,', 'including structured (particularly procedural), object-oriented', 'and functional programming.']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
words = sent.split(' ')
sent_list = [' '.join(words[n:n+5]) for n in range(0, len(words), 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A little unorthodox perhaps:

```
sent_list = [re.sub(r'\s$','',x.group('pattern')) for x in 
     re.finditer('(?P<pattern>([^\s]+\s){5}|.+$)',sent)]

['Python is dynamically-typed and garbage-collected.',
 'It supports multiple programming paradigms,',
 'including structured (particularly procedural), object-oriented',
 'and functional programming.']
```

Explanation `'(?P<pattern>([^\s]+\s){5}|.+$)'`:

- `(?P<pattern> ... )`: cosmetic, to create a named capture group.
- `([^\s]+\s){5}`: find sequence of non-whitespace characters (one or more) followed by a whitespace; and then repeated 5 times.
- `|.+$`: once the first option is exhausted, simply get the last bit through to the end.

We use [`re.finditer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) to loop through all the `match objects` and grab the match with `x.group('pattern')`. All but the last match will have an extra whitespace at the end; one way to get rid of it, is to use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub).

Answer (score 0):

```
sent = 'Python is dynamically-typed and garbage-collected. It supports multiple programming paradigms, including structured (particularly procedural), object-oriented and functional programming.'
sent_list = ['Python is dynamically-typed and garbage-collected.', 
            'It supports multiple programming paradigms,', 
            'including structured (particularly procedural), object-oriented', 
            'and functional programming.']

new_list = []
inner_string = ""
sentence_list = sent.split(" ")
for idx, item in enumerate(sentence_list):
    if (idx+1)==1 or (idx+1)%5 != 0:
        if (idx+1) == len(sentence_list):
            inner_string += item
            new_list.append(inner_string)
        else:
            inner_string += item + " "
    elif (idx+1)!=1 and (idx+1) % 5 == 0 :
        inner_string += item
        new_list.append(inner_string)
        inner_string = ""
        
print(new_list)
print(new_list == sent_list)
```

Output:

```
['Python is dynamically-typed and garbage-collected.', 'It supports multiple programming paradigms,', 'including structured (particularly procedural), object-oriented', 'and functional programming.']
True
```